# Can domains on the same server have dedicated SSL certificates and common files?

Tags: php, windows, linux, ssl

I currently run a number of domains on the same VPS with a managed provider. Each domain would require their own dedicated SSL certificate for ecommerce security, and also require access to a bunch of common scripts that each domain uses. (These scripts are in a central location on the server and each domain can access them).

With the current VPS solution, I am only capable of having one of the two requirements (Either dedicated SSL certs, or files that every domain can access; impossible to have both on a number of VPS hosting I have looked at).

Seeing both of these are a requirement, **is there a server configuration that would allow this? Linux or Windows? Managed or unmanaged? ... recommendations?**

*On my local machine, running WAMP, files can be shared among domains but I have yet to investigate SSL functionality.*

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no technical reason that prevents multiple virtual hosts -- with different SSL certificates -- from accessing the same files, provided they're all hosted on the same system.  There's not any real relationship between a URL and your filesystem, and you're free to have http://domainA.example.com/ and http://domainB.example.com/ point at exactly the same files.

Multiple independent SSL certificates typically requires multiple IP addresses (in general, you can't do named-based virtual hosting over SSL).  A single system can host multiple IP addresses, although your VPS provider may require that systems only have a single unique IP (which may be the root cause of the limitation you've encountered).

Certainly some VPS providers support this (e.g., Linode addresses this [explicitly](http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_IPs)).